# Android when to save heavy data?

Tags: android, save

I have an Android app using the classic Gallery-Editor structure, implementing one activity per each. You choose (tap) a picture from the gallery, and the editor activity launches via Intent. When you hit the back button, you get back to the gallery.
So far so good.

The thing is, the save of the file takes 5-10 seconds (and can't be faster) depending on hardware... so, when should I save?

According to [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

- onPause() will lock the next activity from starting.
- onStop() will not finish saving before the Gallery is on foreground (and needs to read whatever is saved by then).

So, when?

is my only option to save in another thread and flag everybody on finish?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to save on a separate thread, and flag the App class with a "saving" state.
Then, all starting activities check against that state, and react according (showing a "saving" progress dialog for example).

If someone needs example code, please comment and will post something (can't post the exact code due to privacy issues, but can post something from scratch if needed)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to startActivityforResult from the gallery activity. When the picture is edited, setResult with that bitmap in the second activity. In onActivityResult, get the bitmap and show it in the gallery of the edited picture. Parallelly write the image to file in a thread.